# i don't see silverlight project on test.aspx in Firefox,explorer etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i try to learn silverlight but i don't understand why silverproject cannot show on SilverlightTest page

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <Canvas x:Name="cnvLayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblText" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="30" Text="Not clicked yet."></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.Left="30" Click="btnTest_Click" Content="Click me!"></Button>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

### C# codes

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
    TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SilverlightApplication1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div  style="height:100%;">
            <asp:Silverlight ID="Silverlight1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" MinimumVersion="3.0.40307.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant (as I have used the `asp:Silverlight` control successfully myself), but Visual Studio generates the following code in the test aspx page when I create a Silverlight project:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Can you try this and see if it makes a difference? As this doesn't then the problem must be somewhere else.

How have you included your user control on `MainPage.xaml`?

Comment: your codes result give same result. How can i see silverlight app on explorer or firefox

Comment: @ykaratoprak - OK, can you post the `MainPage.xaml` code then? I think I'll need to see how you are using your user control.

Comment: @ykaratoprak 
1. check whether xap file is being copied to ClientBin folder of asp.net project

2. See if you are getting any javascript error because of any execption.

Answer (score 0):

I've just pasted your XAML into a new project and run it in both IE and FF, check you web project properties in the Silverlight Applications section that your Silverlight proj is referenced.